# Version mismatch vite and quasar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, quasar-framework

Trying to install Quasar on my Vite (Vue 3) project. Getting the following error:

```
$ npm install -D @quasar/vite-plugin@latest  sass@1.32.12
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: diop-dash@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @vitejs/plugin-vue@4.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0" from @quasar/vite-plugin@1.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@quasar/vite-plugin
npm ERR!   dev @quasar/vite-plugin@"1.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

From this it looks like quasar's vite plugin is looking for the 2.0.0 or 3.0.0 version of @vitejs/plugin-vue but I have 4.0 installed. Is quasar not compatible with the new one, will I run into trouble if I use the `--force` flag? Is there another way to resolve this that doesn't involve downgrading my Vite setup?

From package.json

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@quasar/extras": "^1.15.8",
  "pinia": "^2.0.28",
  "quasar": "^2.10.2",
  "vue": "^3.2.45",
  "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.2.3",
  "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.1.4",
  "@types/node": "^18.11.12",
  "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
  "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
  "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.0",
  "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.1.3",
  "eslint": "^8.22.0",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.3.0",
  "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
  "prettier": "^2.7.1",
  "sass": "^1.32.12",
  "typescript": "~4.7.4",
  "vite": "^4.0.0",
  "vue-tsc": "^1.0.12"
}
```

Comment: You have found the answer yourself pretty much, you need to downgrade it to the given range. It is indeed not supposed to work with the current version.

Comment: I have had trouble trying to figure out how to install an older version of vite. Something like `npm create vite@3` doesn't seem to do it. It still comes down with vite 4.

Comment: Try `npm i vite@3`.